# How to remove TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY view on touch

Tags: android, service, overlay

I want to remove TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY view which is added on Android service it is possible. my service is..

**OverlayService Service**

```
    public class OverlayService extends Service {
    WindowManager wm;
    View myView;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0, 0,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
                PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_charging, null);


        myView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("==== Remove View ");
                wm.removeView(myView);
                return false;
            }
        });

        wm.addView(myView, params);
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRemoveView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Remove View" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

as per my above code the view is added on screen when app is call but in that button click is not working,what i want..I want to  remove that created view on button click , if it is possible to remove custom TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY then how ..? help me..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably fixed it or moved on but just in case:

The reason its not responding is because I could not get `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` to respond to touch events. The way to do this is use the type `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` and to use the flags:

```
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
```

Then it should respond correctly with the rest of your code.